# Does usb4 host support usb 3.2 gen2x2 devices?

Tags: usb

I'm considering to buy an external SSD drive with usb 3.2 gen 2x2(20Gbps) support.

My MacBook Air M1 has spec for its 2 Thunderbolt/USB4 ports supporting:

- USB 4 (40Gb/s)
- USB 3.1 Gen 2 (10Gb/s)

I called Apple to make clear if their USB4 port (downward) supports USB3.2 Gen 2x2 SSD drive - they answered me "Maybe and maybe not; it depends on vendors' drive".

I called the Taiwan's manufacturer Transcend. They answered me "If our product doesn't explicitly mention usb4, then it probably can not work with MacBook's usb4 host and make use of its usb 3.2 Gen 2x2(20Gbps, up to read/write 2000MB/s).

Nobody knows!? ... even though I have seen usb4's documentation "USB4's lowest speed is half-speed 20Gbps (USB 3.2 Gen 2×2); its highest speed is full-speed 40Gbps".

Even it's said that USB4 is downward compatible with "USB 3.2", I still can not judge if it will co-work in the "USB 3.2 Gen 2x2" mode with the drive like the Transcend's.(which doesn't mention usb4)

――――――――――――――――

My question is:

When the usb4 document says "The minimum functions usb4 host must provide are Gen2x2 20Gbps and DisplayPort Alt Mode", do they mean it can communicate with usb 3.2 Gen2x2 device in 20Gbps? (Despite its tunneling mode, which is new and different from usb 3.x)

Comment: If I wanted to by external storage I would consider PCIe M.2 enclosure: https://ziketech.com/products/zikedrive-worlds-first-and-fastest-usb4-ssd-drive?variant=42809341608097

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in *Figure 5-1 USB4 Discovery and Entry Flow Model* and *Figure F-1 TBT3 Discovery Flow* in *[USB Type-C Spec R2.3 - October 2023](https://www.usb.org/document-library/usb-type-cr-cable-and-connector-specification-release-23)*:

If your device is not a USB4 or TBT3 device, meaning nothing about these two are mentioned on the product, USB4 or TBT3 protocol won't even start. To be more precise you case exit the flow chart at first `Exit TBT3 Discovery`.

Here `Discover Identity SOP` is a part of Power Delivery protocol and by receiving the response from the device host will figure out the max speed.

[image: Figure F-1 TBT3 Discovery Flow]

Your device is not USB4 or TBT3 so now that is out of the picture. If your host supports USB 3.2 Gen 2x2(20Gbps) then you are good to go. But MacBook Air M1 only mentions *USB 3.1 Gen 2 (up to 10Gb/s)* which means it is not supporting your device at full speed.

Reaching high speeds is not just about quality of the connection. Your device and host must also understand that protocol.